# Largest empty rectangle with base on the X-axis among a set of points in 2D

Tags: c++, algorithm, computational-geometry, rectangles

[Original Problem: Problem 2](http://www.iarcs.org.in/inoi/2015/zco2015/zco2015-afternoon.pdf)

In a rectangular space whose height is 500 and width is 10^5, we are given N points.

We're supposed to find out the largest sub-rectangle whose base is on the x-axis and does not contain any of the points in its proper interior (but may contain them in its edges).

I tried an O(width^2) algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

const int nWidth = 100000;
const int nHeight = 500;

int main(){

  int *nMaxHeights = new int[nWidth];
  std::fill (nMaxHeights, nMaxHeights+nWidth, nHeight);

  int N;
  std::cin >> N;
  for (int x,y,iii=0; iii < N; iii++){
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    nMaxHeights[x] = std::min(y+1, nMaxHeights[x]);
  }

  int maxArea = 0;
  for (int jjj,iii=0; iii < nWidth; iii++){
    for (jjj=iii; jjj < nWidth; jjj++){
      if (nMaxHeights[jjj] < nMaxHeights[iii])
        break;
    }
    maxArea = std::max((jjj-iii+1)*nMaxHeights[iii],maxArea);
  }

  std::cout << maxArea;   

  return 0;
}
```

It works, yet obviously receives a TLE (Execution Time Limit Exceeded).

How do I do better?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.  Thanks for pointing these out.

I used an algorithm, that scales `O(N)` for larger `N` (number of points) and a random distribution of points.  The idea behind it: Each rectangle will be bounded by some point(s).

1. If there are more points for one x value, only the one with lowest y value is used.
2. First check the extreme x points; most right and most left, spanning a rectangle to the resp. limits.
3. Then go the the rightmost point and try to build a rectangle including it.  There are two possibilities:

   1. this point is on a horizontal edge: Find its two neighbours, left and right, that have lower y value, and use them as points on the left resp. right edge.  If there is no left/right neighbour, use the end of the space.
   2. this point is on a vertical edge: Find the next-left point, use (y-) limit of the space as horizontal edge.
4. For each point, compute the possible rectangles' areas (the two possibilities above), and if any is bigger than the current biggest area, update the biggest area.

Here is some sample implementation in python, http://pastebin.com/068ByYwh, but I'm not positive, that it does not contain bugs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine just one point. There are three possible rectangles: below the point, to left of it and to the right of it.

Let's say there are two points now. Let's look at the one closer to the bottom first. Again, there are three cases at this step. There's a rectangle below this point. There's also a rectangle on the side opposite of the other point. And there's the side with the other point, where there are more rectangles.

IOW, if you look at the points bottom up, then every point has a rectangle underneath and this point divides the space into two vertical bands, in each of which there are other points, which similarly have rectangles underneath and which further subdivide the space.

So, it would seem reasonable to sort the points by both Y and X (perhaps, by making them nodes of two sorted trees, one sorted by Y (so you can move up in Y) and the other sorted by X (so you can move/search left/right)), which is N*log(N), and then recursively visit all points bottom up, appropriately subdividing the space, which looks like another N*log(N).

Answer (score 0):

My solution below doesn't involve any heavy-duty computational geometry approaches - no sweeping line, no plane partitions etc. The algorithm is based on following ideas:

- The point set is sorted by point x-coordinate
- Two boundary points are added to simplify calculations - `(0,1)` and `(100000,1)`
- All the inscribed rectangles are divided into two types - bounded from above by some point, and bounded from above by the maximal height limit (`=500`) only (I call them "unbounded")
- The trivial rectangle, bounded from above by the point with minimal y-coordinate is the initial estimate for the largest rectangle

So, the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using Duration = std::chrono::duration<double>;

constexpr int WDT = 100'000;
constexpr int HGT = 500;
constexpr int NUM = 100'000;

using Point = struct {int x, y;};
using Rectangle = struct {int xMin, xMax, yMax, area;};
using PVec = std::vector<Point>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& S, Rectangle const& R)
{
  S << '{' << R.xMin << ',' << R.xMax << ',' << R.yMax << ',' << R.area << '}';
  return S;
}

auto initRandom(unsigned const N)
{
  PVec res;
  res.reserve(N);
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dx(1, WDT - 1), dy(1, HGT - 1);
  for (auto i = 0U; i < N; ++i) res.emplace_back(Point{dx(gen), dy(gen)});
  return res;  
}

int main()
{
  auto const tStart = Clock::now();
  auto v = initRandom(NUM);
  // ------ find the area of the lowest and widest rectangle
  auto const pMin = std::ranges::min(v, {}, [](Point const& P){return P.y;});
  Rectangle result{0, WDT, pMin.y, WDT * pMin.y};
  std::cout << result << std::endl;
  // ------ add boundary points and sort the vector of points by x-coordinate
  v.emplace_back(Point{0, 1});
  v.emplace_back(Point{WDT, 1});
  std::ranges::sort(v, {}, [](Point const& P){return P.x;});
  // ------ scan all the unbounded from above rectangles
  int xLft = 0;
  for (auto i = 1U; i < v.size(); ++i)
  {
    auto const xRht = v[i].x, area = (xRht - xLft) * HGT;
    if (result.area < area)
    {
      result = {xLft, xRht, HGT, area};
      std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
    xLft = xRht;
  }
  // ------ scan all the bounded from above rectangles
  for (auto i = 1U; i < v.size() - 1; ++i)
  {
    auto const yMax = v[i].y;
    if (yMax > pMin.y)
    {
      int j = i - 1;
      while (j >= 0 && v[j].y >= yMax) --j;
      auto k = i + 1;
      while (k < v.size() && v[k].y >= yMax) ++k;
      auto const xLft = v[j].x, xRht = v[k].x, area = (xRht - xLft) * yMax;
      if (result.area < area)
      {
        result = {xLft, xRht, yMax, area};
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
  // ------ output timing
  Duration const elapsed = Clock::now() - tStart;
  std::cout << "Elapsed: " << elapsed.count() <<  " sec." << std::endl;
}
```

Experiments show that the largest empty rectangle for a **random** point set with large number of points (>1000) will be the trivial rectangle `{0,100000,0,1}` in most cases - and it's understandable, because such a point set is really dense.